# why does timeBetweenShots = 0 if shotsPerSecond > 1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im making a game where you shoot up at things falling down and i want to make a system where you can upgrade how fast you can shoot. I've made a script where it gets the shotsPerSecond variable (integer variable that determines how many times you can shoot a second) and does 1 / shotsPerSecond to get timeBetweenShots (float variable that determines the time between each shot depending on the shotsPerSecond variable. So if shotsPerSecond was 2 it would do 1 / 2 and would come out to 0.5 and would and then it would only let you shoot if the timer was greater then 0.5)

```
public class Bullet_Shoot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bullet;
    [SerializeField] private float timer;
    public int shotsPerSecond = 1;
    public float timeBetweenShots;

    private void Start()
    {
        timer = 100;
        timeBetweenShots = 1 / shotsPerSecond;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Shoot1")  && timer >= timeBetweenShots)
        {
            Instantiate(bullet, gameObject.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

But whats happening is whenever shotsPerSecond is greater than 1 timeBetweenShots just comes out to 0. Does anyone know why?

i tried rearranging some code but nothing has worked at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called **integer division**. An integer divided by another integer is still... an integer. Therefore when doing division with integers for both operands any floating point (decimal) portion of the result is truncated and lost.

I also see this code assigns the result to a float. However, each expression within a full statement must be able to stand alone, so the `1 / shotsPerSecond` expression must fully resolve *as an integer* **before** the result can be assigned to the `timeBetweenShots` float value.

You can fix this by ensuring at least one of the division operands is also a floating point value. That way you're no longer doing integer division:

```
timeBetweenShots = 1.0 / shotsPerSecond;
```

Comment: since the result is a `float` you should rather use a `float` there as well like `1.0f / shotsPerSecond` or simply `1f / shotsPerSecond` (@OP good practice is to go with the first for better visibility that this is not an `int` ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I am right, but it could be the int converted into the float which may or may not lose accuracy.

Just tested it. It seems my hypothesis was right.

Try changing the seconds to a float and it should work!

Comment: Nope. The fix is correct, but this is mistaken about the reason it works. Also, my mother used to live in Shaumburg.

Comment: Yea I'm Kind of new to coding terminology. 

Only worked 1 year 5 months in the field so far, but I love it!

Cool! Schaumburg is a nice neighborhood!